# How to create a H2O data frame in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, h2o

[Edited for clarity] I'd like to create a H2O data frame in Python with a given number of rows and columns. I can see that [there is a nice function in R](https://rdrr.io/cran/h2o/man/as.data.frame.H2OFrame.html). Is there a corresponding one in Python?
Just to be precise, let's say I want to create a H2O dataframe of zeros with 10 rows and 5 columns. How do I do that? Something like this doesn't work:

```
h2o.createFrame(rows = 10, cols = 5, value = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `h2o.H2OFrame()` function that takes several types of input (list, tuple, dictionary, Pandas DataFrame, Scipy sparse matrix).  More info on the `H2OFrame` constructor [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html#h2o.frame.H2OFrame), and general info about data manipulation in H2O [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging.html).

Example:

```
import h2o
hf = h2o.H2OFrame([[2,3],[4,5]])
```

Comment: Thank you Erin, it looks this works also with numpy objects like this: `h2o.H2OFrame(np.zeros([10,5]))`